# Multiple Move Fx in GXT3

Tags: gwt, gxt

When I press a button I want a container to move in a direction, and after that to do another move. The problem is that only one move command is executed (the second one).

```
centerContainer.getElement().<FxElement>cast().setXY(bounds.getX() - compWidth, bounds.getY(), new Fx(800));
centerContainer.getElement().<FxElement>cast().setXY(bounds.getX(), bounds.getY()+500, new Fx(800));
```

How can I do two moves, one after another ?

Thank you,
Horatiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Fx fx = new Fx(INTERVAL);
 fx.addAfterAnimateHandler(new AfterAnimateEvent.AfterAnimateHandler() {
 @Override
 public void onAfterAnimate(AfterAnimateEvent event) {
     //second move implementation
   }
 });
```